# Get RadioButton value with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

I can get the value of text input from a form.

Like this:

```
<label for="lblName">Name (*):</label>
<input type="text" name="txtBoxName" id="txtBoxName">
```

I submit the form with a validation check first:

```
<form name="contactDataForm" action="sendMail.php" onsubmit="return ValidationCheck()" method="post">
```

This is sendMail.php:

```
$Name = $_POST['txtBoxName'];
```

This works, but how you do it for a RadioButton value? The selected radio button value.

```
<input type="radio" name="test1" id="test1" value="test1" required> TEST 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="test2" id="test2" value="test2"> TEST 2<br>
```

Comment: Usual radio button's names should be same. Meaning only one of them should be selected. If you're looking for multiple selection you can use **checkbox** or you can continue with this!

Answer (score 2):

A radio button is used for selecting a single value from multiple values. So, there will be *only one single name* for all the radio buttons and the values for each of them may vary. You can get the value using the usual $_POST['name'] in PHP.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Radio 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Radio 2
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value"3">Radio 3
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['radio']))
        {
            echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the 2 radio buttons with the same `name` attribute `test1` [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

you will find the radio button value at your PHP server with

```
$radioValue = $_POST['test1'];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a standard HTML Form. A HTML form always gives the value of the selected radio button. If you have a 2 radio buttons with the same name value this will work. The selected radio button will then post your answer to the server. You can then get the value the same way.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So it is exactly the same as with a textinput?

Comment: Yes, if your name value of the radio buttons are the same you will get the selected radio button on post.

Comment: @user7998549 name of every radio button in a group is usually same. But the values are different!